# How to find_all(id) from a div with beautiful soup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to print out all the IDs from a page which has a unique class.

The page what I want to scrape with Beautiful Soup is like this:

```html
<div itemscope itemprop="item" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="12345" class="realestate"> 
<div class="contentArea"> 
<meta itemprop="name" content="Name - 12345 " /> 
<meta itemprop="url" content="https://url12345.hu" />   
<meta itemprop="category" content="category1" />   
</div>
</div>
<div itemscope itemprop="item" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="12346" class="realestate"> 
<div class="contentArea"> 
<meta itemprop="name" content="Name - 12346 " /> 
<meta itemprop="url" content="https://url12346.hu" />   
<meta itemprop="category" content="category1" />   
</div>
</div>
```

the 'ID' is a unique identifier from the Itemscope DIVs, so somehow I want to extract these uniques IDs and print all of them out (the reson is to attach all other ad information to this ID (like name, URL, etc.) later)

I tried with this python code, but it does not work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('searchResultPage.url')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
id = soup.find_all('id')
print(id)
```

It gives back an empty list.

What I expect, and what I want is to get back a list with the ID-s from the divs, this way:
12345
12346

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HS-nebula is correct that find_all looks for tags of a certain type, in your soup id is an attribute not a type of tag. To get a list of all id's in the soup you can use the following one liner

```py
ids = [tag['id'] for tag in soup.select('div[id]')]
```

this uses CSS selectors instead of bs4's find_all since I find bs4's docs regarding its built-ins lacking.

So what the `soup.select` does is return a list of all div elements which have an attribute called 'id' then we loop over that list of div tags and add the value of the 'id' attribute to the ids list.

Comment: Often think it's a shame (unless I've missed something) that BeautifulSoup doesn't expose the underlying parser used... in this case - since it's `html.parser` it doesn't matter... but were it `lxml.html` for instance, then this'd just become a `.xpath('//*/@id')` query...

Comment: Just to note: the BS4 approach to that `.select` would be `soup.find_all(id=True)`

Comment: I think they mention that bs4 uses `html.parser` by default somewhere but didn't see it explicitly stated when I just checked. Didn't know the `.xpath` query was possible when using an lxml parser! Thanks for adding the `.find_all` version. I was looking in the bs4 docs for the equivalent `.find_all` and couldn't work out the proper parameters.

Comment: Err no... `.xpath` isn't available if you use `lxml.html` as a parser in BS4, you don't get the underlying parsed object... if you did something like: `lxml.html.fromstring(page.text).xpath('//*/@id')` that'd do it, but if you're doing something like that anyway, you're probably not likely to be using bs4 in the first place...

Comment: Ah okay misunderstood what you meant, thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: I tried  --> ids = [tag['id'] for tag in soup.select('div[id]')]   <-- but got error did some search and --> ides = [tag.get('id') for tag in soup.select('div[id]')]  <-- worked  just added .get('id')

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to see all IDs in the whole web URL this will work but it will also include lots of the outer and inner HTML tags and code.

```
id = soup.find_all(id=True)
print(id)
```

If you want to see the actual IDs without all the HTML in a list/array of one ID per a row here is an option:

```
for ID in soup.find_all('div', id=True):  
    print(ID.get('id'))
```

In the above For Loop, you are specifying the tag in quote marks, i.e. 'div' and you then are asking it to list the attribute you want, i.e. 'id=True'

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup's find_all() function finds all HTML tags of a certain kind. `id` is not a tag, it's an attribute of a tag. You have to search for the tags that contain the IDs that you want, in this case, the `div` tag.

```
div_tags = soup.find_all('div')
ids = []
for div in div_tags:
     ID = div.get('id')
     if ID is not None:
         ids.append(ID)
```

BeautifulSoup also provides the capability to find tags with specific attributes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between tag and attribute, in your case `div` is the tag and `id` is the attribute of the tag. So you must use `find_all(name='tag')` to find all the tags and after you can use `get('attribute')` to get the attribute. If you want to **scrape** long pages, you can optimize a bit your code by using comprehension list:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup=page, 'html.parser')
test = [r['id'] for r in soup.find_all(name="div", attrs={"id":"12346"}) if r.get('id') is not None]
```

Output:

```
['12345', '12346']
```

Moreover, you can use `find_all()` to get all tags that do have an `id` attribute (thank you Jon Clements), for example:

```
test = [r['id'] for r in soup.find_all(name="div", attrs={"id":True})]
```

Comment: You can finesse that list-comp by using `soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': True})` that only returns elements that do have an `id` attribute so your `if` check in the list-comp becomes redundant as the attribute is going to exist.

Comment: I didn't know this, thank you, I updated the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions :
If only tags with id to be considered:

```
tags = page_soup.find_all(id=True)
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.name,tag['id'],sep='->')
```

If need to loop all tags:

```
 tags = page_soup.find_all()
    for tag in tags:
        if 'id' in tag.attrs:
            print(tag.name,tag['id'],sep='->')
```

Just to get all ids only:

```
ids =[tag['id'] for tag in page_soup.find_all(id=True)]
```